# How to rewrite URL for user profile in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My user profile URL looks like this: `http://mysite.com/profile.php?user=Rango` and I want to make it like: `http://mysite.com/Rango`

Maybe somebody can help with an example? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Fury it would work on https as well, if I remember correctly.

Comment: This is giving `500 Internal Server Error` to me. i'm using `index.php` in place of `profile.php`

Comment: @anujsharma9196 changing filename should not be an issue. could be an error somewhere else. check the errorlog file, it may give you some insight.