# create user friendly url containing username in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, user-friendly

I want to pass username in url just like what other social networking sites like facebook do.
The url should be like : `www.mysite.com/username`

Also I want to be able to access directories if the value at place of username is a directory name.

Ex. `www.mysite.com/downloads` will take to the `downloads` directory.

For this what I can do is to first check where the value passed is a valid directory name. If yes, access directory else check for whether user exists with the username passed.

for this what I have done is, created a `.htaccess` file in root directory containing

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

and checking for the url

```
// requested url
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// trim last / if available
$url = rtrim($request,'/');
// explode url and save in $ar array
$ar = explode('/',$url);

if(sizeof($ar) > 2)
{
  header('location : error/?error=1');
} else {
  $user = $ar[1];
}
```

The if statement above is to check for passed parameter is one or more.
Ex. `www.mysite.com/username/post` will result in an invalid url

But by this code, I couldn't access my directory `www.mysite.com/downloads`
what is the easy way to do this.

> Edit 2 :

I want the url `www.mysite.com/username` to pass `username` as variable *if is not a directory or file* to `index.php` in `myProfile` directory where it is access as `$user = $_GET['u'];`

updated `.htaccess`

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /
Options All -Indexes

# Timezone
SetEnv TZ Asia/Kolkata

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myProfile/index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rewrite URL for user profile in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703091/how-to-rewrite-url-for-user-profile-in-htaccess)

Comment: Thanks @Henders for sharing the link but following the answer there, it is giving `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: @anubhava I have updated `.htaccess` and a little more description.

Comment: `www.mysite.com/username` is giving `404` error and is showing `404 error page`

Comment: `.htaccess` is in root directory ie., at `www.mysite.com` which contain a subdirectory `myProfile` and an `index.html` page. Yes `www.mysite..com/myProfile/index.PHP?u=username` is working from browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in **`/.htaccess`**:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ myProfile/index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you still get `404` then verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `/.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit `www.mysite.com/index.php?u=username` URL in browser.

Comment: This is working as expected but it is working on `www.mysite.com/myProfile/username` and not on `www.mysite.com/username`